# mySQL query not returning unique prices for each option

Tags: mysql

I am running the following mySQL query which is returning the incorrect price for each product option.  (Each option has a different price for testing purposes).

How can I return the individual prices for each option?

The DB schema can be seen here:
http://www.webassist.com/tutorials/Free-eCommerce-MySQL-Database

```
SELECT ProductName AS productname, ProductCategoryID, 
pov.OptionGroupName AS groupname,
povd.OptionName AS optionname, 
pd.OptionPrice as price

FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN productoptions pd ON (p.ProductID = pd.ProductID) 
LEFT JOIN optiongroups pov ON (pd.OptionGroupID = pov.OptionGroupID) 
LEFT JOIN options povd ON (pov.OptionGroupID = povd.OptionGroupID)

WHERE p.ProductID = 1
GROUP BY groupname, povd.OptionName
```

Currently getting this (note the prices):

```
+-------------+-------------------+-----------+------------+-------+
| ProductName | ProductCategoryID | GroupName | OptionName | Price |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------+------------+-------+
| Item1       | 1                 | Color     | Black      | 2.00  |
| Item1       | 1                 | Color     | Red        | 2.00  |
| Item1       | 1                 | Color     | Blue       | 2.00  |
| Item1       | 1                 | Size      | Small      | 5.00  |
| Item1       | 1                 | Size      | Medium     | 5.00  |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------+------------+-------+
```

Should be like this (with unique prices):

```
+-------------+-------------------+-----------+------------+-------+
| ProductName | ProductCategoryID | GroupName | OptionName | Price |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------+------------+-------+
| Item1       | 1                 | Color     | Black      | 2.00  |
| Item1       | 1                 | Color     | Red        | 3.00  |
| Item1       | 1                 | Color     | Blue       | 4.00  |
| Item1       | 1                 | Size      | Small      | 5.00  |
| Item1       | 1                 | Size      | Medium     | 6.00  |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------+------------+-------+
```

Here are data sets for all tables concerned (thanks for the guidance, Strawberry!).

Products Table

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
| ProductID | ProductName | ProductCategoryID |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
| 1         | T-Shirt1    | 1                 |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
```

OptionGroups Table

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| OptionGroupID | OptionGroupName |
+---------------+-----------------+
| 1             | color           |
| 2             | size            |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

ProductOptions Table

```
+-----------------+-----------+----------+-------------+---------------+
| ProductOptionID | ProductID | OptionID | OptionPrice | OptionGroupID |
+-----------------+-----------+----------+-------------+---------------+
| 1               | 1         | 1        | 2.00        | 1 (color)     |
| 2               | 1         | 2        | 3.00        | 1 (color)     |
| 3               | 1         | 3        | 4.00        | 1 (color)     |
| 4               | 1         | 4        | 5.00        | 2 (size)      |
| 5               | 1         | 5        | 6.00        | 2 (size)      |
+-----------------+-----------+----------+-------------+---------------+
```

Options Table

```
+----------+---------------+------------+
| OptionID | OptionGroupID | OptionName |
+----------+---------------+------------+
| 1        | 1             | black      |
| 2        | 1             | red        |
| 3        | 1             | blue       |
| 4        | 2             | Small      |
| 5        | 2             | Small      |
+----------+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: both results have unique price for each row ...your sample is not clear ...

Comment: The query is taking the first price for a given option (in this case, the price for Black which is $2) and repeating it for all other 'color options'.  Currently all COLOR options are $2 when only "Black" should be $2.  Red is $3.  Blue is $4).
You can see how it 'SHOULD' look in my next example, which has unique prices for each option.

Comment: A corresponding data set would be fun

Answer (score 1):

I took your query, scaisEdge, and made some changes to it.  I removed the min/max stuff, changed the way the Left Join was done on ProductOptions, and changed the Where clause and Group By.  Seems to be working correctly:

```
+-------------+-------------------+-----------+------------+-------+
| ProductName | ProductCategoryID | GroupName | OptionName | Price |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------+------------+-------+
| Item1       | 1                 | Color     | Black      | 2.25  |
| Item1       | 1                 | Color     | Red        | 3.25  |
| Item1       | 1                 | Color     | Blue       | 4.25  |
| Item1       | 1                 | Size      | Small      | 5.25  |
| Item1       | 1                 | Size      | Medium     | 6.25  |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------+------------+-------+
```

The Query at this point:

```
SELECT ProductName AS productname, ProductCategoryID, 
  pov.OptionGroupName AS groupname,
  povd.OptionName AS optionname, 
  pd.OptionPrice AS price,
  povd.OptionID AS optionid

  FROM products p 

  LEFT JOIN productoptions pd ON (pd.OptionID = optionid) 
  LEFT JOIN optiongroups pov ON (pd.OptionGroupID = pov.OptionGroupID) 
  LEFT JOIN options povd ON (pov.OptionGroupID = povd.OptionGroupID)

  WHERE p.ProductID = 1 and povd.OptionID = pd.OptionID

  GROUP BY povd.OptionID, 
  groupname, povd.OptionName
```

Thanks a lot for your help on this, scaisEdge.

And thanks to Strawberry for guiding me on how to format my questions on the site.

I truly believe that if a member 'down-votes' a question they should be required to explain why, so that we newbies can learn without simply being demoted and learning nothing from it.

Comment: FYI, this seems to also work fine without the whole Group By clause.